# Optimize a query with IN() clauses oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, optimization, query-optimization, sql-execution-plan

Here I have a query like below:

```
SELECT /*+ USE_NL_WITH_INDEX(D) */ N.MARCHE,N.NLBIX,D.NUORD,D.NUCON, 0 NUBI2, N.COINF, D.COINL, D.COINA, D.COINV, N.COINN, D.COINC, D.NUCPT, D.COINI, N.COINK, N.CNACT, N.NUCAR
FROM VBANET N, VBADET D
WHERE N.MARCHE IN ('DDL')
AND D.MARCHE(+)= N.MARCHE
AND D.NUBIX(+)= N.NUBIX AND N.CTFNE NOT IN ('T','R') 
AND
D.CTFRE(+) != 'R' AND (N.NLBIX IN (SELECT /*+ UNNEST NO_USE_HASH_AGGREGATION */ DISTINCT FN.NLBIX
FROM DICCRN FN, RICCRD FD
WHERE
FN.MARCHE IN ('OCC') AND
FD.NLBIX(+)= FN.NLBIX AND
FD.MARCHE(+)= FN.MARCHE AND
( FN.NUSEQ IS NOT NULL OR FD.NUSEQ IS NOT NULL )) )
```

How can I optimize this subquery :

```
(N.NLBIX IN (SELECT /*+ UNNEST NO_USE_HASH_AGGREGATION */ DISTINCT FN.NLBIX
    FROM DICCRN FN, RICCRD FD
    WHERE
    FN.MARCHE IN ('OCC') AND
    FD.NLBIX(+)= FN.NLBIX AND
    FD.MARCHE(+)= FN.MARCHE AND
    ( FN.NUSEQ IS NOT NULL OR FD.NUSEQ IS NOT NULL )) )
```

because it generate :
|   7 |   VIEW PUSHED PREDICATE                        | VW_NSO_1 |   181K|
|   9 |     HASH JOIN RIGHT OUTER                      |          |   181K|    15M|  7690   (1)|

[THIS IS THE EXECUTION PLAN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eqc1Y.png)

Comment: Please use modern join syntax. It's difficult to read outer joins from the 80s.

Comment: how can i write it with modern join plz?

Answer (score 1):

This is a comment that doesn't fit in the comments secion. I rewrote the query using modern join syntax, so it's easier for me (and others) to understand it. It takes the form:

```
select
  n.marche,n.nlbix,d.nuord,d.nucon, 0 nubi2, n.coinf, d.coinl, d.coina,
  d.coinv, n.coinn, d.coinc, d.nucpt, d.coini, n.coink, n.cnact, n.nucar
from vbanet n
left join vbadet d on d.marche = n.marche 
                  and d.nubix = n.nubix
                  and d.ctfre != 'r'
where n.marche in ('ddl') -- IN #1
  and n.ctfne not in ('t','r') -- IN #2
  and n.nlbix in ( -- IN #3
    select distinct fn.nlbix
    from diccrn fn
    left join riccrd fd on fd.nlbix = fn.nlbix
                       and fd.marche = fn.marche
    where fn.marche in ('occ') -- IN #4
      and (fn.nuseq is not null or fd.nuseq is not null)
  )
```

`IN` #1, #2, and #4 are trivial, so we can assume you want to optimize #3.

First, you don't need `DISTINCT` in the subquery. But more importantly, you can use `EXISTS` instead of `IN` that offers more opportunities for optimization, provided there are good indexes that can be used (there should be).

**EDIT**: Rephrasing using EXISTS

Now that I see the query better, I think it can be rephrased to use `EXISTS` as:

```
select
  n.marche, n.nlbix, d.nuord, d.nucon, 0 as nubi2, n.coinf, d.coinl, d.coina,
  d.coinv, n.coinn, d.coinc, d.nucpt, d.coini, n.coink, n.cnact, n.nucar
from vbanet n
left join vbadet d on d.marche = n.marche 
                  and d.nubix = n.nubix
                  and d.ctfre <> 'r'
where n.marche = 'ddl'
  and n.ctfne not in ('t','r')
  and exists (
    select 1
    from diccrn fn
    left join riccrd fd on fd.nlbix = fn.nlbix
                       and fd.marche = fn.marche
    where fn.nlbix = n.nlbix
      and fn.marche = 'occ'
      and (fn.nuseq is not null or fd.nuseq is not null)
  );
```

The `EXISTS` subquery can benefit from the indexes:

```
create index ix1 on diccrn (marche, nlbix, nuseq);

create index ix2 on riccrd (nlbix, marche, nuseq);
```

Comment: thank you so much but i read about EXISTS it's used effectively with small table in my case the EXISTS may not improve my query

Comment: I applied your solution with exists statement and the add of indexes and my plan now look more efficient  thanks so much